# How to stop Windows mapped network drive randomly spinning up my NAS

Tags: windows, nas, mapped-drive, spinup

Is there a way to stop windows from automatically reconnecting to my NAS, causing it to spin up, when I'm not actually accessing it?

In particular I really dislike hearing it spin up the enclosed hard drives because I hear that is what diminishes their lifespan the most under normal conditions (citation needed).

Comment: Is turning off the NAS an option? Or a physical power switch for the drives (if your system supports hot swapping drives)?

Comment: what NAS? What programs and services are running? Does the NAS support the `Wake-on-LAN` technology? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN